# ScreenWidth wrong value or ListView WidthRequest strange behaviour

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to place three quadratic frames per row in a [`FlowListView`](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView).

---

### xaml:

`FlowListView` code:

```
<toolkit:FlowListView 
    FlowColumnCount="3"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    FlowRowBackgroundColor="{Binding WidgetMainColor}"
    Margin="10,0,10,0"
    FlowItemsSource="{Binding TestContainer.WidgetsInContainer}">
    <toolkit:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame
                Margin="5"
                WidthRequest="{Binding WidthAndHeightForDashboard}"
                HeightRequest="{Binding WidthAndHeightForDashboard}"
                BackgroundColor="{Binding WidgetMainColor}"
                CornerRadius="2"
                HasShadow="False"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</toolkit:FlowListView>
```

---

### Calculation of width/height for the Frame:

`WidthAndHeightForDashboard`:

```
public double WidthAndHeightForDashboard
{
    get
    {
        // -50 for Margin (6 * 5 for Frame margins, 2 * 10 for FlowListView margin)
        // rest is divided by 3 because we need 3 frames
        return (double)(App.ScreenWidth - 50) / 3; 
    }
}
```

---

I am using `ScreenWidth` to calculate `WidthAndHeightForDashboard` because I know that the page will always be in portrait mode. This means we will have more height than width on this page, so width is decisive for a quadratic frame.

`ScreenWidth` is calculated like this:

```
App.ScreenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
```

### Screenshot of my outcome

As you can see in the screenshot, frames are taller than wide, but they should be quadratic:

[image]

I also tried to remove all margins and remove margin from the calculation in case that I have a fault in my calculation, but this does not fix the issue.

`WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` are using the same value but the frames are taller than they are wide, so I am pretty sure that the calculated value for `WidthAndHeightForDashboard` is higher than it should be... Or maybe there is less space on the screen that stated by `App.ScreenWidth`?

Comment: Does `App.ScreenWidth` give the correct behavior? There are sveral size conceps on mobile platforms and if it deviates, this might be the source of your issue. Have a look at the width of your `FlowListView` once it is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what exactly happened, but I managed to find a workaround (or the right solution to do this? I don't know):

Instead of setting `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` of the `Frame`, I now set the `Padding` for the `Frame` which I calculate like this:

```
return (double)(App.ScreenWidth - 30 - 3 * IconWidthAndHeight) / 6;
```

I'll explain the calculation with this image:

[image]

> 30 = Summary of the width margins in the current row (5 + 10 + 10 + 5)
>
> 3 * IconWidthAndHeight = I have 3 Widgets with 46x46 size
>
> Divide by 6 so get the value of the padding

Sorry, I know this doesn't exactly answer the original question because I didn't include the image in the question. But maybe this is helpful for someone out there!